# Enlarge partition, can’t boot install usb

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am on a Lenovo yoga c930 dualbooting Win10 and Ubuntu 20.04.

I want to enlarge my Ubuntu partition.

I have freed up space from my Win10 partition and created an Ubuntu installation disk. I have changed my bios UEFI to boot the usb second (EFI is first and locked).  Secure boot is enabled

When I boot the grub menu gives me the standard options including Ubuntu, advanced options, WIN and UEFI firmware. No installation option.

Ubuntu and advanced options seem to take me to my default user profile.

It’s been a long time since I installed.  How do I boot into the install usb without being forced into my default profile?

Comment: How you boot the live/installation media is the exact same way you did when you installed Ubuntu. If your Lenovo has a one-time boot menu / boot override menu, use that as it doesn't change the working boot order, it boots the external media this one time only. Other than that you may have a boot override setting at uEFI > Boot, also preferable to actually changing the current and working boot order.

Comment: Thanks.  I can’t remember what I did two years ago when I installed.  Whatever I did, the live / usb is not working with my boot loader. 
There is no one time option in my Lenovo boot setup.  Just USB device boot which I have enabled. (Also usb to lan which is disabled).

Comment: It is NOT supposed to work with/from your currently installed bootloader. Booting from external media is controlled by the firmware (BIOS or uEFI). And F12 (or FN+F12) *is* the Lenovo one-time boot menu. It needs (1) the USB media connected before powering on, obviously, and (2) quick action, there's only a small time frame for users to press the key, before any attempt to load the installed OS/bootloader. Old(ish) but still valid: https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht500207-how-to-boot-from-usb-disk-in-the-bios-boot-menu-windows-8-windows-10-ideapadlenovo-laptops